# Why doesn't this code work properly???I mean,why does it not show anything when I run it?

Tags: c++, overloading

Is there any problem in overloading methods?I really think it should work but it doesn't.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class BIGINT
{
    vector<int> big_number;
public:
    BIGINT(){}
    BIGINT(int);
    BIGINT(string);
    BIGINT operator+(const BIGINT&)const;
    BIGINT operator+(int)const;
    BIGINT& operator+=(const BIGINT&);
    BIGINT& operator==(const BIGINT&);
    vector<int> get_bn() { return big_number; }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const BIGINT&);
};
```

//constructors

```
BIGINT::BIGINT(int n)
{
    vector<int> temp;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int a;
        a = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        temp.push_back(a);
    }
    for (int i = temp.size() - 1;i > 0;i--)
    {
        big_number.push_back(temp[i]);
    }
}

BIGINT::BIGINT(string sn)
{
    vector<char> temp;
    for (int i = 0;i < sn.size();i++)
    {
        temp.push_back(sn[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < temp.size();i++)
    {
        big_number.push_back(temp[i]-48);
    }
}
```

//overloading operator+

```
BIGINT BIGINT::operator+(const BIGINT& bn) const
{
    BIGINT temp;
    int size;
    int k = 0;
    if (bn.big_number.size()>big_number.size()) size = big_number.size();
    else size = bn.big_number.size();
    for (int i = size - 1;i > 0;i--)
    {
        if(k)
        {
            if (big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i]>9)
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i] - 10 + 1);
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i] + 1);
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(big_number[i]+bn.big_number[i]>9)
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i] - 10);
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i]);
                k = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    return temp;
}

BIGINT BIGINT::operator+(int n)const
{
    BIGINT temp;
    int size;
    int k = 0;
    vector<int> temp_int;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int a;
        a = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        temp_int.push_back(a);
    }
    if (temp_int.size()>big_number.size()) size = big_number.size();
    else size = temp_int.size();
    for (int i = size - 1;i > 0;i--)
    {
        if (k)
        {
            if (big_number[i] + temp_int[i]>9)
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + temp_int[i] - 10 + 1);
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + temp_int[i] + 1);
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (big_number[i] + temp_int[i]>9)
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + temp_int[i] - 10);
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.big_number.push_back(big_number[i] + temp_int[i]);
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}


BIGINT operator+(int n, BIGINT bn)
{
    BIGINT temp;
    int size;
    int k = 0;
    vector<int> temp_int;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int a;
        a = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        temp_int.push_back(a);
    }
    if (temp_int.size()>bn.get_bn().size()) size = bn.get_bn().size();
    else size = temp_int.size();
    for (int i = size - 1;i > 0;i--)
    {
        if (k)
        {
            if (bn.get_bn()[i] + temp_int[i]>9)
            {
                temp.get_bn().push_back(bn.get_bn()[i] + temp_int[i] - 10 + 1);
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.get_bn().push_back(bn.get_bn()[i] + temp_int[i] + 1);
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (bn.get_bn()[i] + temp_int[i]>9)
            {
                temp.get_bn().push_back(bn.get_bn()[i] + temp_int[i] - 10);
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.get_bn().push_back(bn.get_bn()[i] + temp_int[i]);
                k = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    return temp;
}
```

//overloading operator+=

```
BIGINT& BIGINT::operator+=(const BIGINT& bn) 
{
    int size;
    int k = 0;
    if (bn.big_number.size()>big_number.size()) size = big_number.size();
    else size = bn.big_number.size();
    for (int i = size - 1;i > 0;i--)
    {
        if (k)
        {
            if (big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i]>9)
            {
                big_number[i] = big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i] - 10 + 1;
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                big_number[i] = big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i] + 1;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i]>9)
            {
                big_number[i] = big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i] - 10;
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                big_number[i] = big_number[i] + bn.big_number[i];
                k = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    return *this;
}
```

//overloading operator==

```
BIGINT& BIGINT::operator==(const BIGINT& bn)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < big_number.size();i++)
    {
        big_number[i] == bn.big_number[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

//overloading operator<<

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BIGINT& bn)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < bn.big_number.size();i++)
    {
        out << bn.big_number[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

//main

```
int main()
{
    BIGINT a(123);
    BIGINT b(2);
    BIGINT c;
    c = a + b;
    cout << c << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh man, wall of text. what happened when you stepped through it in a debugger?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to include that instead. This is a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: Debugger.  Use the Debugger.  Or use the ancient art of *Print Statement Debugging*.

Comment: Specifically, which statement is not working?  What is the actual value?  What is the expected value?  What are the inputs to replicate the issue?

Comment: I think it should show "125" on the screen which it doesn't. - @ThomasMatthews

Comment: @Vahid When you use a debugger, and you step into the statement `BIGINT a(123)` does it set up `a` the way you thought it should? How about `b` and `c`? When you stepped into the function `c = a + b` did it do what you thought it should? If it isn't giving you what you expect, then in at least 1 place it isn't doing what you think it should. Where is the first place where it does something different than what you think it should? If you don't understand at that specific line why it behaves like it does, then tell us what that 1 line does that you don't understand, and we can help you.

Comment: In your constructor, why the use of `temp`?  Why not directly use `big_number`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews because I want to place digits in left-to-right order and if I don't use a temp vector digits will  be place reversely.For example 123 will be saved 321.I put a for loop to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a waste of computing resources:

```
for (int i = 0;i < big_number.size();i++)
{
    big_number[i] == bn.big_number[i];
}
return *this;
```

Probably violating one of the top 10 directives of computing:
*Results of computations shall be stored in a variable or memory.*

*So, you compared two array slots.  So waht, big deal.*

Why are you returning a copy of the object?
*Remember, by mathematics, you return either `true` or `false` from comparing, not the object compared to.*

How about something like this:

```
bool BIGINT::operator==(const BIGINT& bn)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < big_number.size();i++)
    {
        if (big_number[i] != bn.big_number[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The loop is terminated upon finding the first set of slots that are not equal.  There is no point on searching the remainder of the array.  There only needs to be one inequality to prove the equality wrong.

**Edit 1:  Length of containers for equality**
For containers to be equal, they must be of the same size or have the same number of elements.

Thus the equality function now becomes:

```
bool BIGINT::operator==(const BIGINT& bn)
{
    if (big_number.size() != bn.big_number.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < big_number.size();i++)
    {
        if (big_number[i] != bn.big_number[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```